# Can Entity Manager be shared by two servlets?

Tags: servlets, deployment, jpa-2.0

I have packed my common classes (domain objects, utilities and JPA2 - persistence service) into one jar. I include the jar into my libs for two other applications and configure the persistence unit and entity manager for each application independently. Both apps are deployed as servlets on the same tomcat. But if one applications manipulates data of the MySQL-DB the other application does not use the updated data.

How can I use a centralized Persistence Service and allow all application acces to up to date data? Do I have to use JNDI or package everything as EAR instead as single WARs?

Comment: You need a shared L2 cache for JPA. This problem is not related to servlets.

Comment: The mention of servlets are only meant to depict a particular use case.

Comment: Okay. Merely pointing out that this can't/shouldn't be solved using Servlet API facilities.

Comment: As far as I can see sharing a L2 Hibernate cache is done by using terracotta. In my case this seems like breaking a butterfly on a wheel. Is the no other option? How would a basic setup look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to using 2 different JPA applications that hit the same database.  In this case, each app using its own L2 cache will exacerbate the problem.  You could get the applications to synch their L2 caches as mentioned in comments.  Or you can evaluate the EntityManager usage and ensure they are not held for extended periods or they are occasionally cleared.  Only obtain the EM when needed, and close or clear it when done the process.  If not using an L2 cache, this will ensure that data is read in from the database as needed more in line with transactional operations.

Stale data can happen even in a single application usage, so it is strongly recommended to use optimistic locking to avoid overwriting with stale data.